# Editing spatial data with ArcGIS Server .NET 

Tags: c#, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have a Mapserver application with SDE layers... 
I´d like to know how can I edit my SDE spatial data (add/edit a point/line layer) in .NET ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to solve that:

- Multi-Versioned View : http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_multiversioned_views
- Using Soap : http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/soap/index.htm

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ArcSDE then your only solution is to use ESRI's ArcObjects in a .NET language of your choice.

It seems a strange to have a combination of MapServer (I presume this is the OpenSource MapServer?) and SDE.

If you store features in SQL Server 2008 (or Oracle, or PostGIS) then you have more editing options - but then you lose SDE features such as more complex typologies, versioning etc.